# Laravel setup for basic API and AJAX-calls

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, redirect

**Laravel POST return type?**

I'm setting up an API alpha version using basic auth single sign on.
Cant debug with postman/js because its not returning JSON but redirecting me instead. From what Ive read AJAX calls shouldnt be redirected? Do I have errors in the configuration?

Routes:

```
Route::post('/test1', 'tradesCtrl@test1']);
//Route::post('/test1', ['middleware' => 'auth.basic.once', 'uses' => 'tradesCtrl@test1']);
```

AJAX call:

```
$.post( 
    "http://localhost:8000/test1",
{
    p1:"100a",
    p2:80
},
    function(data, status,jqXHR){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Controller (this will echo HTTP (!):

```
public function test1(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        echo "AJAX!";
    } else {
        echo "HTTP!";
    }         
}
```

Allow cross domain for now in App.php

```
// allow origin
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Kernel.php disable csrf protection by commeting out

```
app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

If I try to insert validation for parameters

```
public function test1(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'p1' => 'Integer',
        'p2' => 'Integer'
    ]);                   
    echo "Serving stuff";        
}
```

This immediately return in a 404 page not found when failing validation, probably a redirect to something else that's not working??

Comment: Laravel 5.1, jQuery 2.1.4.

Comment: Try using an actual response via `return response()->json(array('somekey' => 'someval'))` from your controller

Comment: Yes that's working. But the validation still causing 404... However, emptying validation rules: $this->validate($request, []); does work. Ive tried to follow the trace but cant find why that is

Comment: echo $request->method(); says POST